# FreeTextBox causing permission denied error

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel, permission-denied, freetextbox

I am using a freetextbox control on my asp.net page. It is causing a Permission Denied pop up message, but not always when I am working with the freetextbox directly.
Example: I can submit the text from the freetextbox to the database with no problem. Then, when I click another control on the page (completely unrelated) the error comes up. If i remove the freetextbox everything works fine.
Has anyone experienced similar issues with the freetextbox?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi,Same issue with me... Its making me bald. Please guys help us out....

Comment: 1 : which version of FreeTextbox? 2 : On which browser ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I installed the application, the permission denied error no longer appeared. I'm unsure why. It still occurs when i run from visual studio. If anyone can figure out how to prevent it prior to installation that would be helpful. I'll just deal with it for the time being as it won't screw up in production.